# IE doesn't support 'insertBefore'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a problem with this piece of code :

```
    var logo = document.getElementById("move_this");
    prependElement('container', logo);

    function prependElement(parentID, child) {
        parent = document.getElementById(parentID);
        parent.insertBefore(child, parent.childNodes[0]);
    }
```

In IE I have an error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'insertBefore'

Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Searching, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172202/does-ie7-not-fully-support-javascripts-insertbefore-method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use it like that:

```
var parent=document.getElementById(parentID);
```

otherwise parent will be global, but there always is a global parent-object, the [**parent**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window(and it is read-only).

**Furthermore:**
IE requires as 2nd argument a valid node or null, so be sure that parent has childNodes to avoid errors:

```
parent.insertBefore(child,(parent.hasChildNodes())
                            ? parent.childNodes[0]
                            : null);
```

Comment: `(parent.hasChildNodes())?parent.childNodes[0]:null` can be shortened to `parent.childNodes[0] || null`

Answer (score 5):

`insertBefore` works correctly in `IE` as long as the 2nd parameter is a valid DOM element, or `null` ( `typeof null` is `Object` and so is a `typeof` DOM element).

For an `Array`, any out of bound index (which in this case is `0` as the `children[]` is empty) will return `undefined`. IE stops working in the following case as the 2nd param becomes `undefined` -

```
parent.insertBefore(child, parent.childNodes[0])
//parent.childNodes[INDEX]
//where `INDEX` is greater than parent.childNodes.length
```

So, a better approach for this case will be

```
var refEl  = parent.childNodes[INDEX] || null;
parent.insertBefore(newRowHolderNode.childNodes[0], refEl);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned above, `.insertBefore` works only with valid node (explicit ID or global document reference). Local variable reference would fail:

```
parent.insertBefore(child, localref); //error
```

In IE we can use `.sourceIndex` property to get current global index of "marker" element, before which new child is inserted. Here is the fix for IE:

```
parent.insertBefore(child, document.all[localref.sourceIndex]);
```

It is not necessary to use `.sourceIndex` property, if you know exactly where in parent tree you wish to insert an element. Following properties works just fine:

```
parent.insertBefore(child, parent.all[1]); //must be a child
parent.insertBefore(child, parent.children[2]); //any sane index
parent.insertBefore(child, parent.firstChild); //if at least one child exists
parent.insertBefore(child, parent.lastChild); //if at least one child exists
parent.insertBefore(child, localref.nextSibling]); //if not last child
parent.insertBefore(child, localref.previousSibling]); //if not first child
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.