# D3: "Invalid argument" error using d3.js in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, svg, d3.js

I am trying to to get maps working in IE9 using d3.v3.js, world-110m.json and topojson.v1.js (I'm also using jQuery 10.1 so that is loaded too).  It works fine in FF and Chrome but, as I am aware, IE 8 and below do not have native SVG support and therefore cannot be supported without workarounds.

Unfortunately, IE9 does not seem to work either.  An error is thrown in the IE 9 console:

SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
d3.v3.js, line 726 character 4

```
    d3_selectionPrototype.insert = function(name, before) {
        name = d3_selection_creator(name);
        before = d3_selection_selector(before);
        return this.select(function() {
          return this.insertBefore(name.apply(this, arguments), before.apply(this, arguments));
        });
    };
```

Line 726 is "return this.insertBefore" etc.  Any ideas what's going on and how to resolve?

Comment: FWIW: I discovered that this error was introduced in d3 ver. 3.2.3 (it's now at 3.3.6). I contacted Mike Bostock about this. He made a slight edit to d3.v3 that eliminates this error. Line 777: return this.insertBefore(name.apply(this, arguments), before.apply(this, arguments) || null);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 doesn't implement insertBefore quite the same way as other browsers. More detail in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377887/ie-doesnt-support-insertbefore) I suspect that in your case the second argument is null.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  Sadly this is being thrown in IE9 which is supposed to handle d3.v3