# Changing row order in a table - prevent changing the header

Tags: javascript, html

the code below allows reordering of table rows (moving a row up or down)

for some reason, the following code in IE11 allows changing the header row as well , although i specified "tbody tr:first" as my filter
what am I doing wrong?

```js
  function upAction(){
   var row = $("input[name='select_radio']:checked").parents("tbody tr:first");    
   row.insertBefore(row.prev());
  }
  
  function downAction(){
   var row = $("input[name='select_radio']:checked").parents("tbody tr:first");
   row.insertAfter(row.next());
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <button onclick="upAction()">Up</button>
 <button onclick="downAction()">down</button>
<table  >
    <tr>
       <th>Printer</th>
       <th>Printer ID</th>
       <th>Printer Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="select_radio"/></td>
                <td>x300</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>new printer installed in 3th floor</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="select_radio"/></td>
                <td>x400</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>laser printer</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="select_radio"/></td>
                <td>Office jet 3</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>old student printer</td>
              </tr>
  
              </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377887/ie-doesnt-support-insertbefore

Comment: Try using a `<thead>`.

Comment: Just to elaborate on Malk's correct response: IE will actually put any unwrapped `<tr>` into a `<tbody>`. The problem with your specific example is that it's taking your independent header `<tr>` and wrapping it in its own `<tbody>`, so your HTML is actually interpreted by IE as `<table><tbody> (header) </tbody><tbody> (body)</tbody></table>`

Comment: Wrap all the table content outside the <tbody> within a <thead> tag.